# How do you write definition of this template?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

How do you write the definition of this template?

```
fun<10>();// output is 10  
fun<20>();// output is 20
```

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
template <int32_t N>
void fun() {
    std::cout << N << std::endl;
}
```

It is called a non-type template parameter.

And the parameter here (`int32_t N` for instance in the above example) can be one of the following types (until C++20):

> 1. std::nullptr_t (since C++11);
> 2. an integral type;
> 3. a pointer type (to object or to function);
> 4. a pointer to member type (to member object or to member function);
> 5. an enumeration type.

Reference: [template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters)

Comment: Can you add context to the code you posted as answer?

Comment: @mjuarez what context? It's a free function.

Comment: The comment was posted 6 months ago, because it was essentially the code only.  It has now been addressed.